# ES5 : mocha and qunit.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, qunit

I have qunits written using QUnit.js, now I am trying to integrate Qunit.js with mocha so that I can execute both unittests with single mocha command.

I have installed qunit and mocha using npm.

```
➜ npm ls

├── mocha@10.2.0
├── qunit@2.19.3
├── sinon@15.0.1
├── ts-node@10.9.1
└── typescript@4.9.4
```

And when I tried to run the mocha command

```
> mocha --require qunit --package ./package.json ./*.js

ReferenceError: QUnit is not defined
```

I am using ES5 JS Syntax, so I can't add lines like require in my `.js` files. Is there any way we can achieve this?